# Datapicker for jQuery 2.1.1 - how ?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I found datepicker plugin for version 1.1.1 of JQuery, but it does not works on 2.1.1. Is there a version for jQuery 2.1.1 ?

Comment: did you look at http://jqueryui.com/? are you getting confused by the jQuery ui version (currently 1.11.1)? will work with jQuery 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using date-picker include jquery.ui.all.css in your page and it will work